# How do I deal with certificates using cURL while trying to access an HTTPS url?

Tags: curl, https

I am getting the following error using curl:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
```

How do I set this certificate verify locations?

Comment: What OS/distro are you on? You should install the ca-certificates package (that's what it's called on debian/ubuntu).

Comment: For future reference, I had already `ca-certificates` installed but the error persisted. The problem was that my certificates were located in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` instead of `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, so I just had to set the environmental variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` to the correct path.

Comment: Cool! It works for me when I set `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Comment: and where do you change this variable? In what file?

Comment: hit this when pycurl==7.45.3 was released in pypi in debian bullseye (docker image python:3.8-slim-bullseye) with ca-certificates installed

Comment: This issue and the solution are in https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/834  (go to CURL_CA_BUNDLE_AUTODETECT)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

This error is related to a *missing package*: `ca-certificates`. Install it.

In Ubuntu Linux (and similar distro):

```
# apt-get install ca-certificates
```

In CygWin via [Apt-Cyg](https://github.com/cfg/apt-cyg)

```
# apt-cyg install ca-certificates
```

In Arch Linux (Raspberry Pi)

```
# pacman -S ca-certificates
```

---

The documentation tells:

> This package includes PEM files of CA certificates to allow SSL-based applications to check for the authenticity of SSL connections.

As seen at: [Debian -- Details of package ca-certificates in squeeze](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ca-certificates)

Comment: ca-certificates is already the newest version, yet I'm still getting the error

Comment: Of course, you'll get this same error if you try to install apt-cyg via the recommended method using curl and https://raw.github.com.

Comment: Works for me in MSYS2. Thanks!

Comment: Same as Pastor Bones; this answer is poor.

Comment: On Arch Linux, you might also need `pacman -S ca-certificates-utils`. I did.

Comment: how to do it in windows?

Comment: @PastorBones If you're still getting the error, simply reinstall - I fixed in cygwin64 on Windows 10 by doing: `apt-cyg remove ca-certificates` and then `apt-cyg install ca-certificates`

Comment: This package is already installed.  This answer is not helpful.

Comment: @PastorBones I had the same issue that the package was already latest, I think it had however been corrupted so a `sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates` reinstalled the package and resolved the errors I was seeing

Comment: I realize that it is perfect for dockerfile to get composer installed, thanks

Comment: For anyone using Linux (Ec2) use `sudo yum install ca-certificates`

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 169):

I also had the newest version of ca-certificates installed but was still getting the error:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

The issue was that curl expected the certificate to be at the path `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` but could not find it because it was at the path `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Copying my certificate to the expected destination by running

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

worked for me. You will need to create folders for the target destination if they do not exist by running

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs
```

If needed, modify the above command to make the destination file name match the path expected by curl, i.e. replace `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` with the path following "CAfile:" in your error message.

Comment: You could also create a symbolic link with `ln -s` if don't want to re-copy it every time you update it.

Comment: Had same problem for `rescuetime` app on Fedora 25. `sudo ln -s /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-certificates.crt` solved the problem. (`CURL_CA_BUNDLE` env var didn't work)

Comment: On my ubuntu this fixed the issue: `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.pem`. I was actually getting `The repository ... does not have a Release file` which was caused by missing certificate ( `Could not load certificates from ...` ).

Answer (score 108):

Put this into your `.bashrc`

```
# fix CURL certificates path
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

(see comment from Robert)

Comment: Thank you for providing a method that doesn't require me to muck up system files by hand, but still keeps the security of using certificates!

Comment: Thank you. This solved my similar problem with pyenv & curl. I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and already had ca-certificates installed.

Comment: This approach also works with xonsh (add `$CURL_CA_BUNDLE = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"` to the `.xonshrc`).

Comment: Just in case: The one liner version of this: `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/bundle.crt curl http://example.com`

Comment: This was a life-saver. Curl kept looking for certificates at a path that didn't exist on my system - specifically {USER}/Desktop/src/master/cert.ca. I have no idea where it got that from. This single export solved everything.

Answer (score 37):

Create a file `~/.curlrc` with the following content

```
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

as follows

```
echo "cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" >> ~/.curlrc
```

Comment: the best answer, this worked for me on Linux Mint 17

Comment: On Mac, it worked with following in `~/.curlrc`

`cacert=/etc/openssl/cert.pem`

Comment: did not work for me / ubuntu 18

Comment: @pascalsautot Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 21):

The quickest way to get around the error is add on the -k option somewhere in your curl request.  That option "allows connections to SSL cites without certs." (from curl --help)

Be aware that this may mean that you're not talking to the endpoint you think you are, as they are presenting a certificate not signed by a CA you trust.

For example:

```
$ curl -o /usr/bin/apt-cyg https://raw.github.com/cfg/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
```

gave me the following error response:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

I added on -k:

```
curl -o /usr/bin/apt-cyg https://raw.github.com/cfg/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg -k
```

and no error message.  As a bonus, now I have apt-cyg installed.  And ca-certificates.

Comment: That might get around the error, but it also makes the "secure" connection become insecure.

Comment: Not really. As far as I know, you can't just bypass the encryption of a secure connection, so it's still encrypted and going to only one endpoint. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but the only risk you run is that you could fall prey to a man-in-the-middle attack. Still not likely a risk if you're using curl.

Comment: Yes, really. The "-k" option is shorthand for "--insecure".  If you have man-in-the-middle what do you think he's doing with your data ?  Spoiler alert: he's decrypting it, stealing it, and possibly modifying it and injecting back into the insecure stream.  Straight from the man page : "-k, --insecure (SSL)  This  option  explicitly  allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k, --insecure is used."

Comment: If you need SSL you need privacy and verification — the `-k` flag means you're **losing** verification. Depending on your needs this may be acceptable. MITM are non-trivial attacks if you assume your network and the server you're communicating with are secured from interlopers (can you make that assumption?). The risk increases depending on the type of you data (sourcecode and certs are riskier than images). You can verify the integrity of the data after the transfer (checksums etc.) but now you're shifting your trust onto that checksum channel. In the end `-k` gives you quite a bit more work.

Comment: So does it mean that if i am using a Self signed certificate. I should be using the option -k. As it may not be possible to verify the Self signed certificate ?

Comment: @Linus: No, `-k` would work with *no certificate*. Self-signed certificates should work (if you tell `curl` about them).

Comment: I'm pretty sure a cert is required for SSL. @Linus you could either use -k, and decide to trust any MITM, or make sure that either your individual cert or the CA you signed with is in your trusted certificates store.

Answer (score 16):

From `$ man curl`:

```
--cert-type <type>
    (SSL) Tells curl what certificate type the provided  certificate
    is in. PEM, DER and ENG are recognized types.  If not specified,
    PEM is assumed.

    If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

--cacert <CA certificate>
    (SSL) Tells curl to use the specified certificate file to verify
    the peer. The file may contain  multiple  CA  certificates.  The
    certificate(s)  must be in PEM format. Normally curl is built to
    use a default file for this, so this option is typically used to
    alter that default file.
```

Answer (score 16):

@roens is correct. This affects all **Anaconda** users, with below error
`curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none`

The workaround is to use the default system curl and **avoid** messing with the prepended Anaconda `PATH` variable. You can either

1. Rename the Anaconda curl binary :)
   `mv /path/to/anaconda/bin/curl /path/to/anaconda/bin/curl_anaconda`
2. **OR** remove Anaconda curl
   `conda remove curl`

`$ which curl
/usr/bin/curl`

[0] **Anaconda Ubuntu curl Github issue** https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/issues/352

Comment: Good find, I didn't realize Anaconda was stealing my path precedence. It worked once I replaced `curl` with the full path `/usr/bin/curl`

Answer (score 13):

If anyone is still having trouble, try this, it worked for me.
Delete the files in your `/etc/ssl/certs/` directory
then reinstall ca-certificates:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates --reinstall
```

Did this when I tried installing Linuxbrew.

Comment: This helped me but I didn't delete the files on my machine. Just ran the simple command and curl started working.

Comment: This was the solution for me 

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem. As it turns out, my `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file was malformed. The last entry showed something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEDTCCAvWgAwIBAgIJAN..lots of certificate text....AwIBAgIJAN-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

After adding a newline before `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, curl was able handle the certificates file.

This was very annoying to find out since my `update-ca-certificates` command did not give me any warning.

This may or may not be a version specific problem of curl, so here is my version, just for completeness:

```
curl --version
# curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/7.51.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2j zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.7.0
# Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
# Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative to fix this problem is to disable the certificate validation:

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Comment: Workaround, but it helps me after too much time with curl certificates. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For PHP code running on XAMPP on Windows I found I needed to edit php.ini to include the below

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

and then copy to a file https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and rename to curl-ca-bundle.crt and place it under \xampp path (I couldn't get curl.capath to work). I also found the CAbundle on the cURL site wasn't enough for the remote site I was connecting to, so used one that is listed with a pre-compiled Windows version of curl 7.47.1 at http://winampplugins.co.uk/curl/

Comment: On windows you can also just add "xampp" before php like so:

curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\cacert.pem"

Answer (score 5):

curl performs `SSL` certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of `Certificate Authority (CA)` public keys (CA certs). The default
 bundle is named curl-ca-bundle.crt; you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.

If this `HTTPS` server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).

If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or `--insecure`) option.

for example

```
curl --insecure http://........
```

Comment: Just an aside that "trusting the source" is pretty irrelevant here, since without properly validating the cert against a CA, you have no idea who "the source" is.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

then go into the certificates folder at

```
sudo cd /etc/ssl/certs
```

then you copy the ca-certificates.crt file into the `/etc/pki/tls/certs`

```
sudo cp ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs
```

#### *if there is no tls/certs folder: create one and change permissions using chmod 777 -R folderNAME*

Comment: I tried this but this didn't work for me and I still get the same error. Any ideas ?

Comment: `chmod 777` is very insecure (anyone - any process - on that box can change the certs and MitM attack you) - `chmod 755` is much better

Answer (score 3):

It seems your curl points to a non-existing file with CA certs or similar.

For the primary reference on CA certs with curl, see: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 3):

Just create the folders, which is missing in your system..

> /etc/pki/tls/certs/

and create the file using the following command,

> sudo apt-get install ca-certificates

and then copy and paste the certificate to the destination folder, which is showing in your error.. mine was " `with message 'error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none' in` " make sure you paste the file to the exact location mentioned in the error. Use the following command to copy paste..

> sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
>   /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Fixed.

Comment: None of the top answers worked for me but this did!

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem : I'm building an alpine based docker image, and when I want to curl to a website of my organisation, this error appears. To solve it, I have to get the CA cert of my company, then, I have to add it to the CA certs of my image.

- Get the CA certificate

Use OpenSSL to get the certificates related to the website :

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername my.company.website.org -connect my.company.website.org:443
```

This will output something like :

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 CN = UbisoftRootCA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
...
```

Get the last certificate (the content between the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and the
`-----END CERTIFICATE-----` markups included) and save it into a file (mycompanyRootCA.crt for example)

- Build your image

Then, when you'll build your docker image from alpine, do the following :

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add ca-certificates curl
COPY mycompanyRootCA.crt  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mycompanyRootCA.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

Your image will now work properly!

Answer (score 3):

I came across this curl 77 problem while was trying to access elasticsearch running in docker container on Ubuntu 20.04  localhost. Afrer container was started:

1. Check curl without ssl: `curl --cacert http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200 -k` lowercase `-k` for insecure connection.
2. Check curl configs: `curl-config --configure`, noticed what is ca-bundle: `--with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.
3. Copy http_ca.crt file from container to:`/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, original command is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/docker.html).
4. Run update on ca-certificates: `sudo update-ca-certificates`.
5. Run curl: `curl -u elastic:<password> https://localhost:9201`.
   Finally got response with `"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"`.

Change <password> to the one that was generated when Docker Image was run.
Also notice that on my machine elastic was started on port 9201  (don't know why: sudo ss -tlpn | grep 9200 gives me nothing), I have found the port with: `sudo netstat -ntlp` and Programm name was docker-proxy.

Answer (score 2):

For windows :-

1. Download the certificate from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Rename cacert.pem to curl-ca-bundle.crt
3. Add the file to any of the below locations

[image]

Check this for details https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: I did `curl https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -k` to get a copy of the root certificate curl needs. I am building linux from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, checking `which curl` is being run is significant too.

A user on a shared machine I maintain had been getting this error. But the cause turned out to be because they'd installed Anaconda (http://continuum.io). Doing so put Anaconda's binary path before the standard `$PATH`, and it comes with its own `curl` binary, which had trouble finding the default certs that *were* installed on this Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I recommend checking `which -a curl` to see everything available, and of course noting which one comes on top.

Answer (score 1):

Just find this solution works perfectly for me.

> `echo 'cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' > ~/.curlrc`

I found this solution from [here](https://youremindmeofmymother.com/2016/03/28/curl-77-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations/)

Answer (score 0):

Run following command in git bash that works fine for me

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. My issue was this file:

```
/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

is by default just an empty file. So even if it exists, you'll still get the error as it doesn't contain any certificates. You can generate them like this:

```
p11-kit extract --overwrite --format pem-bundle /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/ca-certificates/ca-certificates.install

Answer (score 0):

I use MobaXterm which intern uses Cygwin so even after installing `ca-certificates` using `apt-cyg install ca-certificates` problem didn't resolve.

I was still getting the following error:

`curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: none`

Then I tried listing the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and I couldn't find it. However I could find `/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` with all standard CA certificates so I copied the file `/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` as `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error when run **composer update**
And I tried all the commands to reinstall the cert file, but the problem was not solved.

***I realized that the error is due to permission***
So the problem was solved with this command

```
cd /etc/ssl

sudo chmod 755 -R certs/
```

Answer (score -3):

In my case, it was a permission issue

try

```
sudo curl .....
```