# Docker apt-get update fails

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dns

Can somebody help me get apt-get working in my docker container? Whenever I try running any apt-get command in my docker container, the command fails. I'm running Docker version 1.1.1, build bd609d2 on ubuntu 12.04.

When I do

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
# apt-get update
```

I get errors saying

> Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

I tried uncommenting the line below in /etc/default/docker

> DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

but I still can't ping google.com

> ping: unknown host

I confirmed that the container is using the dns servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

> root@0baa87fc6322:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
>
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>
> nameserver 8.8.4.4

and I'm able to ping both servers so I'm pretty sure that a firewall isn't just dropping my packets.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: if a firewall prohibits using an external recursive nameserver, then use the recursive nameserver or caching forwarder available to machines on your LAN. I suppose if you could reconfigure the firewall, you had done so by now, means you're not in a position to change that. Confirm whether it's a firewall using dig @8.8.8.8 google.com, see whether that resolves. if it does, it's not firewall.

Comment: Solved problem by switching away from Google's DNS servers to Cloudflare's @`1.1.1.1` & `1.1.4.4`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Thanks for all your help! I found out it was a dns problem and that it was because of a firewall. After searching some more I found this question that I wasn't able to find while searching 'docker apt-get fail'

[Docker - Network calls fail during image build on corporate network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/docker-network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network)

His problem was similar to mine and the solution helped me get it working.
I've copied over his solution for anybody that finds this question in the future.

> Those Google servers weren't accessible from behind our firewall, which is why we couldn't resolve any URLs.
>
> The fix is to tell Docker which DNS servers to use. This fix depends on how you installed Docker:
>   Ubuntu Package
>
> If you have the Ubuntu package installed, edit /etc/default/docker and add the following line:
>
> DOCKER_OPTS="--dns <your_dns_server_1> --dns <your_dns_server_2>"
>
> You can add as many DNS servers as you want to this config. Once you've edited this file you'll want to restart your Docker service:
>
> sudo service docker restart
>
> Binaries
>
> If you've installed Docker via the binaries method (i.e. no package), then you set the DNS servers when you start the Docker daemon:
>
> sudo docker -d -D --dns  --dns  &

Comment: For those who don't know what's your dns is https://robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/

Comment: FYI, this answer (etc/default/docker) is for older versions of Ubuntu that use Upstart. Since Ubuntu 16.04, it is using systemd, so you will need to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089399 instead.

Answer (score 30):

If you see an error like `Could not resolve ...`, it is likely a DNS configuration.

First thing to check is run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` in the **docker container**. If it has an invalid DNS server, such as `nameserver 127.0.x.x`, then the container will not be able to resolve the domain names into ip addresses, so `ping google.com` will fail.

Second thing to check is run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on the **host machine**. Docker basically copies the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` to the container everytime a container is started. So if the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` is wrong, then so will the docker container.

If you have found that the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` is wrong, then you have 2 options:

1. Hardcode the DNS server in daemon.json. This is easy, but not ideal if you expect the DNS server to change.
2. Fix the hosts's `/etc/resolv.conf`. This is a little trickier, but it is generated dynamically, and you are not hardcoding the DNS server.

---

**1. Hardcode DNS server in docker daemon.json**

- Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

  ```
  {
      "dns": ["10.1.2.3", "8.8.8.8"]
  }
  ```
- Restart the docker daemon for those changes to take effect:
  `sudo systemctl restart docker`
- Now when you run/start a container, docker will populate `/etc/resolv.conf` with the values from `daemon.json`.

---

**2. Fix the hosts's `/etc/resolv.conf`**

**A. Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier**

- For Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier, `/etc/resolv.conf` was dynamically generated by NetworkManager.
- Comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq` (with a `#`) in   `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
- Restart the NetworkManager to regenerate `/etc/resolv.conf` :
  `sudo systemctl restart network-manager`
- Verify on the host: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

**B. Ubuntu 18.04 and later**

- Ubuntu 18.04 changed to use [`systemd-resolved` to generate `/etc/resolv.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html#contenttoc3). Now by default it uses a local DNS cache 127.0.0.53. That will not work inside a container, so Docker will default to Google's 8.8.8.8 DNS server, which may break for people behind a firewall.
- `/etc/resolv.conf` is actually a symlink (`ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`) which points to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` (127.0.0.53) by default in Ubuntu 18.04.
- Just change the symlink to point to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, which lists the real DNS servers:
  `sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
- Verify on the host: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Now you should have a valid `/etc/resolv.conf` on the host for docker to copy into the containers.

Comment: Work for me. :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, /etc/resolv.conf is using 127.0.0.53 but it is not a symlink in my case.

Comment: @wisbucky Please explain how did you get the DNS array 1st value. it is random or how we may get this("10.1.2.3") value.

Comment: @dinu0101 You have to know the DNS server that the host is using (which is a separate question). You could try running `nslookup google.com`, and the first line `Server:` should be it.

Comment: I'm using a vmware ubuntu18.04 in a company's workstation and the 2nd - B option works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Adding { "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"] } works for me.

Answer (score 11):

```sh
$ sudo docker run -i -t --net=host ubuntu /bin/bash
# apt-get update
```

No errors! - Note the added `--net=host`.

---

Below I show how to reproduce the error.
I did the following on a clean machine having nothing but Ubuntu 18.04
installed on it.

First install docker. Copy-paste *one line at a time* and
**hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after *each*
line:**

```sh
sudo apt update                         # took 11 seconds for me
sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates \
curl software-properties-common
```

The second of the two commands above (one command broken up on two lines)
is *optional* and took ~20 seconds for me.

```sh
echo "cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" >> ~/.curlrc
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg \
| sudo apt-key add -
```

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://\
download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

The command above took ~7 seconds for me.

```sh
sudo apt update                         # ~3 seconds this time
sudo apt install -y docker-ce           # ~1 minute for me
```

*Optional* -- if you don't like to prefix `docker` with `sudo` every time:

```sh
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

Log out and back in.
Confirm that `docker` is now added to your groups:

```sh
id -nG
```

---

Now to the **core** part of interest:

```sh
$ sudo docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash  # ~10 seconds for me
# apt update                            # first Err after ~1 minute
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease [...]
...
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, [...]
```

Note how I just recreated the error described by the OP!
The OP got `Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'`,
while I got `Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com`.
But the root cause is the same: the docker container has no access to
the internet.

I don't want to stay in this bad docker container so I hit <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>.
No wish to keep it either, so I do:

```sh
sudo docker container ps -a
```

which tells me that the `CONTAINER ID` in my case is `c05ec98236f0`.

I remove this container:

```sh
sudo docker container rm c05ec98236f0
```

Heads up for something that doesn't give me an error.

```sh
$ sudo docker run -it --net=host ubuntu bash
# apt update                            # ~7 seconds
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
...
Fetched 16.4 MB in 4s (4332 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Voilà! No error!

References:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163#1162198
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909#31424970
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316376#43317607

Comment: just adding --net=host worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First check if you have connection, ping directly to ip `91.189.92.201` that `archive.ubuntu.com` is pointed to:

`ping 91.189.92.201`

If you still can't reach the host it's not a dns problem.

Also if you have internet connection, you can make a hack. Just put a row into `/etc/hosts` file and problem solved:

`91.189.92.201 archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: I can ping to `archive.ubuntu.com` but still it shows me the error `W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease`

Answer (score 3):

I am using the version of Mint and after installing Docker and try to create an image of Ubuntu to do the apt-get update command does not recognize, to remedy the problem,  I did step down

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80  ubuntu /bin/bash
echo "91.189.92.201 archive.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/hosts
cat /etc/hosts
apt-get update
```

Comment: Hi Kor; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: See if improved now!

Comment: Interesting answer but the IP address changed since this was written so one might want to do a DNS lookup to retrieve the most up to date IP address for archive.ubuntu.com before doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the issue in two different case and the resolution was different...

***First one with Win7 + virtualbox(Xubuntu 16.04)***
This comment did the job:https://stackoverflow.com/a/29659783/2260796

I modify the file /etc/default/docker:

> DOCKER-OPTS="--ip-masq=true --dns my_ip_dns_win --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns
>   8.8.4.4"
>   And run 
>   sudo service docker restart

***Second one on a Xubuntu OS (ubuntu 16.04)***
The precedent resolution was not enough.
This comment did the job: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1809
I had to comment one line in file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

> ## dns=dnsmasq

Then run

sudo restart network-manager

Comment: +1 for the `--ip-masq=true`. Very useful if you are behind another firewall and only the Docker host is allowed to talk to the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Jenkins base image and no matter what I do, apt-get update was always failing.
Eventually, this helped, removing ***/var/lib/apt/lists/***   
 and **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ***  did the trick.

```
USER root
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
RUN apt-get update
....Continue using apt-get for installing your stuff..
RUN apt-get install -y maven
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running `docker build` you cannot specify `--net=host`
This case happens.

In this case do:

1. `vim /etc/docker/daemon.json` will be created if doesn't exist. Usually not.
2. Add following content into file

```bash
{
    "dns": ["10.1.2.3", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

3. Restart docker `sudo service docker restart` if you don't want to use `systemctl`

I was using WSL2 Ubuntu. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Error with docker-compose]
I faced the same problem with `docker-compose`. I solve that by adding `ENV http_proxy 'proxy.com'` entry into Dockerfile.

Comment: worked for me thanks. But consider that you should put 'ENV http_proxy 'proxy.com' '   in the same line and 'apt-get update' so both run in the same container.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'ubuntu:20.04' image (previous LTS) instead of 'ubuntu'. It works for me.