# Docker containers - DNS issue

Tags: dns, docker

I have problem running any command requiring internet connection within my Dockerfile script (like calling `apt-get install xyz`), probably due to DNS problems.

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832972/docker-apt-get-update-fails) thread and added `--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4` to `DOCKER_OPTS`. Unfortunately, it didn't help at all, still having issues connecting.

**The only solution** that works so far is to add the following line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN 'echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf'
```

It works, but it's cluttering the Dockerfile a little bit. 
I also tried to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` on my main machine, but it didn't help.

Any suggestions? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-35

**// edit:**

Here's the gradle script to generate Dockerfile:

```
task createDockerfile(type: Dockerfile) {
    dependsOn build
    destFile = project.file('build/Dockerfile')
    from 'java:8'
    volume '/tmp'
    runCommand 'echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf'
    runCommand 'apt-get update'
    runCommand 'apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server'
    runCommand 'service rabbitmq-server start'
    addFile 'libs/notification-bc-*.jar', 'notification-bc.jar'
    runCommand 'bash -c "touch /notification-bc.jar"'
    entryPoint 'java', '-jar', '/notification-bc.jar'
}
```

and the resulting Dockerfile iteslf:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME ["/tmp"]
RUN echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server
RUN service rabbitmq-server start
ADD libs/notification-bc-*.jar notification-bc.jar
RUN bash -c "touch /notification-bc.jar"
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/notification-bc.jar"]
```

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile ? do you always do `apt-get update && apt-get install -y xxx`?

Comment: In my docker script? Yes, I do. I'll edit my question and paste it. It's actually a gradle script, but function names are equivalent to docker commands.

Comment: I have tested your Dockerfile without your `RUN echo nameserver...`and it has worked fine until the line `ÀDD...` that failed as I do not have the required file. I have Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You were able to install rabbitmq package? Could you show me your /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: I find it hard to believe `RUN echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf`has any effect, as /etc/resolv.conf is mounted from the host which should overwrite your change. See https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

Comment: Try removing the `RUN` line and trying again.

Comment: Already tried a few times, this is the only working solution...

Comment: What does the error message say when you build from Dockerfile? Can you post it. Try also running `docker images`, get the image ID from the "incompleted" images, run a container from that image ID and do the troubleshooting from inside the container.

Comment: Yes I was able to install rabbitmq, "Step 4 : RUN service rabbitmq-server start
 ---> Running in 1a286b7f5977
Starting message broker: rabbitmq-server.
 ---> 3e07183ccfcb
Removing intermediate container 1a286b7f5977
Step 5 : ADD libs/notification-bc-*.jar notification-bc.jar
INFO[0061] No source files were specified", my /etc/resolv.conf `nameserver 127.0.1.1`

Comment: sinowak; I tested this myself and I really don't believe your RUN command does anything. What version of Docker are you using and which storage driver?

Comment: Docker version 1.7.0-dev, build 5e06332
How can I chcek storage driver?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem. And the fix for me on Linux was to put the --dns 8.8.8.8 fix in the system service docker.service. On the "ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd" line add --dns 8.8.8.8.
So it should look like

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd  --dns 8.8.8.8
```

You can find this file by looking at

```
systemctl info docker.service
```

on CentOS.
When I added this and then reloaded the configuration and restarted the service everything was working.

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl restart docker.service
```

If you want more information I threw it in a blog post [here](http://darrenpulsipher.blogspot.com/2017/04/docker-containers-with-dns-fix.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and also for mentioning the linked blog is yours. I do however suggest you take a read of [How not to be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) to understand how the site views this kind of linking.

Comment: This solution did not resolve my DNS issues.