# Accessing a remote database using MySQL with the SOCI C++ library from a docker container

Tags: c++, mysql, docker, networking, soci

I have some C++ code that connects to a remote database to obtain some data.

But now I'm trying to make the whole system work inside a docker container and I'm having problems, specially because I don't know a lot about connections, network communication, etc.

I basically have a "connectionString" with all the information, host, port, user, password, etc. The host adress is like example.host.adress and when I execute it I get this error:

Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'example.host.adress' (110)

I already had problems using apt-get with docker and I managed to solve it with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089399/3848742 (the 16.04 fix).

But now I'm having this and I've reading some people with similar problems but I can't get it to work, does anyone know if it's even possible to perform this kind of things, and if so, what could I do to fix it?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: On a non mysql server pc, execute `telnet example.host.adress 3306`, what's output?

Comment: It says "Trying -IP adress- for a couple of minutes and then "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out". Is it not a problem with docker then?

Comment: It seems not related to docker, like related to mysql server itself.

Comment: And, it has nothing to do with SOCI library, so the subject is misleading