# error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile ca-bundle.crt CApath: none

Tags: php, wordpress, certificate

I am trying to install the plugins directly from wordpress admin panel (instead of manual download and install). I am getting this error

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-super-cache.1.4.7.zip…

Download failed. error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /home/xyz/
public_html/domainname.com/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
```

1. I checked the certificate. Its working fine. Even i replaced it with fresh copy. Still I am getting the error.
2. I deactivated other plugins.
3. I checked for file permissions. Its also ok. (Files - 644 and Folder - 755)
4. I contacted hosting support. They searched and tried to solve the issue but they said its not issue on their end.

I am unable to get the root cause. Please provide the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Mahesh

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with certificates using cURL while trying to access an HTTPS url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url)

Answer (score 0):

It was the same problem with me, I'm setting the correct path and I updated php.ini, but it still showing this error!

I found this .pem file which resolved my problem! use it instead of default one

http://ge.tt/4ts7N6n2