# SSL: can't load CA certificate file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Tags: macos, apache, ssl, certificate, vhosts

On my local dev machine (osx), I'm using jboss to server web services on 8443. When I hit the urls directly I get the json responses I'm looking for. The architecture we have at work includes a middle layer (apache/php) that does authentication and routing. If things authenticate then it forwards the request to the backend.

When I was working with apache on port 80 and jboss on 8081 (using http). Everything worked fine for me. Now that I'm trying to use 8443, things aren't working.

I recently changed the backend to server through https (8443) instead of http (8081). I can hit the requests on https 8443 directly and get the json response. When I hit apache and it authenticates then tries to redirect to the https 8443 I get the following message from chrome's inspector: "SSL: can't load CA certificate file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt".

[image]

My vhost is setup to catch *:80 requests. I think I might need to setup vhosts to accept 443 requests or install `ca-certificates` like talked about in [How do I deal with certificates using cURL while trying to access an HTTPS url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url) . I'm looking to see if anyone knows what the proper direction should be.

When I look on the file system, the file `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` doesn't exist. When I make the request to the middle layer, I see the request hit `/var/log/apache2/access_log` and nothing comes up in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`.

What is needed to resolve this issue? Is it a configuration of vhosts to catch request to 443? Is it to install ca-cert stuff like in the link? A combination of both? Or something else? Please provide enough info on how to solve it, or provide links that provide enough info.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue and am doing a post for documentation purposes, in case anyone else has similar issues. There was a couple of issues I had to resolve to fix this.

**PHP Install**

My `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` referenced my default osx php install instead of my home brew install of php. Solution was to edit the httpd.conf and point it to the right install.

```
#LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php53/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29_4/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

You can create a similar setup of php using home brew by the following commands:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php53
brew install homebrew/php/php53-igbinary --build-from-source
brew install homebrew/php/php53-intl
brew install homebrew/php/php53-mcrypt
brew install homebrew/php/php53-memcached
brew install homebrew/php/php53-mongo
brew install homebrew/php/php53-xdebug
```

**Create the CA Cert Bundle File**

The system is looking for `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.cert` which is a standard path on linux, but not on osx. We get around this by generating the file.

I generated the `.keystore` file using `keytool` and used `jboss` for my alias. In order to build the ca bundle file, we need it to be in the pem format, so we need to add the -rfc to our export statement. Below are the commands:

```
cd /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration
keytool -export -alias jboss -file local-sbx.dev.yourcompany.com.crt -keystore .keystore -rfc
```

After you have the file, you can cat it out and verify that the file has the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` stuff in it. If so, its in the right format.

Lastly, create the directory structure, move the cert to act like the bundle (which is just a bunch of certs appended to each other) and then restart apache:

```
mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs/
sudo cp local-sbx.dev.yourcompany.com.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sudo apachectl restart
```