# How to Get Apache to Accept a Self Signed Cert Made By Java's KeyTool

Tags: php, macos, apache, symfony, ssl

Apache/PHP/Symphony is being used in my middle layer for authentication and routing. A request comes through on http then if the request authenticates the person making the request is authorized then makes a call to a backend web service over https. The back end web service is over https with a self signed certificate. I can hit the backend service directly and see my certificate information via chrome inspector. When I make the request directly to the backend via the url, everything works. When I try to go through the middle layer, I get a response back that is a 504:

`{"code":504,"message":"A network communication error has occurred","error":{"code":77,"message":"SSL: can\u0027t load CA certificate file \/etc\/pki\/tls\/certs\/ca-bundle.crt"}}`

I generated the certificate to:

`/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration/.keystore`

Using the command:

`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias jboss -keystore .keystore -storepass changeit -validity 9999 -keysize 2048`

I also updated my standalone.xml to reference the file via:

`<ssl name="ssl" key-alias="jboss" password="changeit" certificate-key-file="/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration/.keystore" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false"/>`

My dev machine is OSX.

It seems that apache or symfony is looking for the cert in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.cert` which is a file that doesn't exist on my system. Searching for "pki" in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` yields no results.

How do I setup `apache`/`symfony2` to trust this cert, or is there a different way to trust this cert more globally?

Answer (score 0):

**Create the CA Cert Bundle File**

The system is looking for `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.cert` which is a standard path on linux, but not on osx. We get around this by generating the file.

I generated the `.keystore` file using `keytool` and used `jboss` for my alias. In order to build the ca bundle file, we need it to be in the pem format, so we need to add the -rfc to our export statement. Below are the commands:

```
cd /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration
keytool -export -alias jboss -file local-sbx.dev.yourcompany.com.crt -keystore .keystore -rfc
```

After you have the file, you can cat it out and verify that the file has the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` stuff in it. If so, its in the right format.

Lastly, create the directory structure, move the cert to act like the bundle (which is just a bunch of certs appended to each other) and then restart apache:

```
mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs/
sudo cp local-sbx.dev.yourcompany.com.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sudo apachectl restart
```

**Note:** This was a sub problem of [SSL: can't load CA certificate file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438170/ssl-cant-load-ca-certificate-file-etc-pki-tls-certs-ca-bundle-crt/36478556#36478556) so if you are still having issues, you might need to update your php setup too... directions are in the link provided.