# BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using python-build 1.2.7)

Tags: python, ubuntu

When I download some Python versions using ***pyenv install 3.6.1***, getting below error during run the command：

```
python@ubuntu:~$ pyenv install 3.6.1
Downloading Python-3.6.1.tar.xz...
->https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz  
error: failed to download Python-3.6.1.tar.xz

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using python-build 1.2.7-7-g21c75c1)
```

---

```
 python@ubuntu:~$pyenv install -v 3.6.1
 Downloading Python-3.6.1.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz 

 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.python.org 
 error: failed to download Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
```

I find the similar problem as this：

1.[pyenv: BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 15.04 using python-build 20160509)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227854/pyenv-build-failed-ubuntu-15-04-using-python-build-20160509)

2.curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.***

```
$sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
# change
nameserver 114.114.114.114
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

But it doesn't work, Is there anyone who can help me?