# ruby install fail on linux mint 17.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu

Im trying to install ruby on linuxmint 17(x64) using the official guide [install rails on ubuntu14](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04) but it fails with below error. my `curl version is 7.45.0`

```
local~# rbenv install -v 2.3.1
/tmp/ruby-build.20160831221528.6331 ~
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
error: failed to download ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (LinuxMint 17.3 using ruby-build 20160602-35-gf08cb5c)
```

Comment: Thisis probably related to issue with ca certificates, try this [question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url)

Comment: i tried "apt-get install ca-certificates" and it was already installed. i was able to install ruby from source though