# Exchange the Authorization Code for an Access Token In OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I am trying to exchange the authorization code (which is in the url of this page) for an access token using oAuth 2.0.

I am running the following php code and am getting an error (http error 500).

I can't figure out what is wrong with the following code.  I have deleted the actual client id, etc- it's there to show the code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://id.shoeboxed.com/oauth/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\",\"client_id\": \"f8de67be8dc84e449203fcdd4XXXXXXX\",\"client_secret\": \"HS5ZeIVsKW0/qqiO9/XcdeWqnF8vtzQrpY8gcdrxg0BXNZXXXXXXX\",\"code\": \"['code']\",\"redirect_uri\": \"http://website.com/foursquare2.php"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: are those CURLOPT_URL etc constant values? if not try to enclose each of them into " or ' example: 'CURLOPT_URL' most likely this is caused by the syntax error.

Comment: Try adding CURLOPT_POST => 1 to the options array instead of CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json string you have in your post fields is not a valid json string.  You can test json here:

https://jsonlint.com/

You might try populating an array with your post fields, then use json_encode() to encode the array to a json sting in your curl request.  This will help mitigate errors when creating your json string.  I greatly prefer doing it this way.

```
$postArray = array(

      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
      'client_id' => 'f8de67be8dc84e449203fcdd4XXXXXXX',
      'client_secret' => 'HS5ZeIVsKW0/qqiO9/XcdeWqnF8vtzQrpY8gcdrxg0BXNZXXXXXXX',
      'code' => '[\'code\']',
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://website.com/foursquare2.php'

);


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://id.shoeboxed.com/oauth/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //<--- Added this.
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",  //<---You may also try "CURLOPT_POST => 1" instead.
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postArray), //<--Makes your array into application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" //<---Change type
  )
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Your new error is a result of not having the appropriate certificates installed on your server.  Here is a link to get you started, if it don't help, SO and google have a bunch of stuff on this.

[How do I deal with certificates using cURL while trying to access an HTTPS url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I added CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false to your options array.  This is a bandaide until you can get your certificate problem figured.  It does potentially expose your data to someone who may be snooping.

Your third issue has to do with the type/format of the data that you are sending to the data to.  It's expecting application/x-www-form-urlencoded and you have stated your content type as application/json.

Here is some reading on the subject:

[How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I tried the code suggested and I think it helped, but it now has a different error: cURL Error #:error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PHPSettings\cacert.pem CApath: none

Comment: This could be for a few reasons, but try adding CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false into the options array

Comment: I made the change just suggested and now get the error: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"mandatory: Content-Type -> application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

Comment: @Rick  That error is stating that the page you are sending the url to required your content type to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of application/json.  Try to change that in your curl request.  You may have to urlencode your json string as well.  It looks like Ive successfully answered a couple of your questions.  Please mark this one as accepted and then do some research on this subject.  If you cant find a answer post another question on SO and let another member who may know a little more about this subject help you.  Thanks and good luck.

Comment: thx.  I changed  it to: "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Now i'm getting the following error: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"invalid grant type"} Do we need to change some syntax?

Comment: @Rick, I have answered the question presented in this post.  Please mark as the accepted answer.  Your error would suggest that you do not have an appropriate authorization code.  Please research OAuth 2.0 procedures and post a new question if you can't figure it out.