# Git certification error when attempting to clone repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone a repository onto my laptop and am facing some issues. The specific installation I'm referring to is the [Twint library](https://github.com/twintproject/twint). Allow me to elaborate:

I first type `git clone https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git` which gives me the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'twint'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git': error setting
  certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

I've looked online and found [this Git issue](https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/issues/36) which one answer states to run

```
git config --global http.sslveify "false"
```

but this also gives me

```
error: could not lock config file /home/User/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know what I should do to fix the issue? Thank you.

**EDIT**

In case it helps, the contents of my `C:\ProgramData\Git\config` file is as follows:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    interactive = true
[help]
    format = html
[rebase]
    autosquash = true
```

Comment: i clone it its working fine

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git`

Comment: try again just copy and past this command be sure that folder have writing access .

Comment: if it still not working please let me know.

Comment: Is this Git installed via Cygwin? You're missing the ca-certificates package. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400988/14660