# how to fix cert location of curl

Tags: curl

when I am using this command in my terminal on MacOS terminal showing this error:

```
curl https://storage.flutter-io.cn/flutter_infra/flutter/0f7cdca65fba5619c02d00bb5faa40a4f1950df7/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
(base)
```

and I check this path, did not have a certifacate. Then I using this command to check the certificate:

```
$ curl-config --ca
/usr/local/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
```

should I using this certificate, how to generate a certificate and make my curl work? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use your curl-config --ca path as cacert path, try this command on bash.

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/your/new/cacert/path
```

For your example, execute this.

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
```

reference:

> [How do I deal with certificates using cURL while trying to access an HTTPS url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909/how-do-i-deal-with-certificates-using-curl-while-trying-to-access-an-https-url#comment59801161_3160909)